# Can I display the date and time column according to users location in power BI?

Tags: date, time, powerbi, timezone

I have data that is a "SharePoint Online" as the source and I need a display a date and time column in the table visual

Currently, I am displaying data in the PST format for "US" if the users' location is in the US and BST if the user's location is "UK" The problem is I am displaying the US and UK timezone on a single date/time column i.e..,

| Location | Date and Time |
| --- | --- |
| US | 06/31/2021 05:30 AM + 8:00 |
| UK | 06/10/2021 07:30 AM + 1:00 |

But The requirement is the "Date and Time" column should be displayed according to the user's current location whenever they log in
It should be in a single column with their own timezones and that should be dynamic It should get the users location and query the data accordingly

For Example:

| Username | Location | Date and Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sarah | US | 06/31/2021 05:30 AM |
| Justin | UK | 05/10/2021 07:30 AM |

When Sarah logins and check for the report the result of the Date and Time should be like below (since Sarah is in US location) the offset should be included to both:

| Username | Location | Date and Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sarah | US | 06/31/2021 05:30 AM+8:00 |
| Justin | UK | 05/10/2021 07:30 AM + 8:00 |

When Justin logins and check the report the result of the Date and Time should be like below(Since Justin is in UK location) he needs to see his location timezone date and time:

| Username | Location | Date and Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sarah | US | 06/31/2021 05:30 AM+1:00 |
| Justin | UK | 05/10/2021 07:30 AM + 1:00 |

Can I display it as above? If yes,please do help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you tried with measure to generate that values dynamically?

Comment: @mkRabbani Yeah I tried but it's not working

Comment: @mkRabbani Local Time = 
var DateTime = SELECTEDVALUE([Date and Time])
var _timezoneoffset=LOOKUPVALUE(
[Offset value],
[EMail],
USERPRINCIPALNAME()
)
return
DateTime +(_timezoneoffset/24) This is the measure I have included